# Coin Score Logic

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, nsuserdefaults, spritebuilder

I created a game similar to flappy bird but added with coin element. I have the high score working but I can't figure out how to make the coin score work. I want the coin score to be added with the previous best coin score when the player restarts the game. Currently, my code only shows the previous best coin score and will not add the coin score individually when the player restarts the game. How do I change the code so that it shows the total coins collected rather than the best coin score?

```
- (void)didLoadFromCCB {
    [self loadSavedState];
}

-(BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair hero:(CCNode *)hero coin:  (CCNode *)coin {
    _coins++;
    if (_coins > _bestCoin) {
        _bestCoin = _coins;
        [self saveState];
    }
    [self loadSavedState];
    return TRUE;
}

//write for coin
- (void)saveState {
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setInteger:_bestCoin forKey:@"bestCoin"];
    [prefs synchronize];
}

//read for coin
- (void)loadSavedState {
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    _bestCoin = [prefs integerForKey:@"bestCoin"];
    _coinLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_bestCoin];
}
```

Comment: You question is not clear. What do you want, show coin count in the label? Where are you increasing you coins?

Comment: Yes, i want to show the total coin count in the label. I'm increasing my coin count in ccPhysicsCollisonBegin.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add coin count to label just write this line where you are  increasing the coin count.

```
_coinLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_bestCoin];
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you want the collected coins to carry over through each play-through as opposed to acting like a high score. If that's the case your problem is that the current coin count is starting at 0 every time you play. This means your if statement in CCPhysicsCollision is not going to get called until you collect more than _bestCoins in one session.

Change your loadSavedState to this:

```
- (void)loadSavedState {
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    _bestCoin = [prefs integerForKey:@"bestCoin"];
    _coinLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_bestCoin];
    _coins = _bestCoin;
}
```